# Building tableview with table view cells with collection view cells that are scrollable in android

Tags: android

I am learning android development. I want to build a table view like IOS where each table cell has multiple collection view cells that you can scroll horizontally. Each table view cell is independent of the next table view cell. Please see screenshot[image]. Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can build this in android?